# Is it correct to say that every locally small category C is a subcategory of the category of presheaves of that same category C?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand the Yoneda Embedding and the Yoneda Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is a correct understanding of the Yoneda Embedding functor. The source where I got my answer is:

[NLab, Yoneda Embedding](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+embedding)
.

The answer is given in the first paragraph of the link I posted.

Understanding concepts is very challenging for a new student in category theory. I hope my question can help someone else also. The Catsters videos on "Representables and Yoneda Lemma" were very helpful, and they caused me to think about the question I had above.

Comment: This may help you: www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/categories/yoneda.ps

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it : )